# search operators?

Tags: search

I have a bunch of old game ROM's I need to search through. The data I need is contained in brackets `[]`. so for example I might be searching for `[b(with a number after)]` or `[a(with a number after)]`. I tried a wild card `[b*]` but that didn't seem to work.

any hints guys?

Edit

Thing is I want to try and delete any files with a certain string. for example. 
name_of_rom [b1].nes

so i need to search for any files with [b*]

Answer (score 3):

Example

```
$ touch \[{a..z}{0001..0009}\]
rinzwind@schijfwereld:~/tmp$ ls
[a0001]  [c0009]  [f0008]  [i0007]  [l0006]  [o0005]  [r0004]  [u0003]  [x0002]
[a0002]  [d0001]  [f0009]  [i0008]  [l0007]  [o0006]  [r0005]  
...
[c0008]  [f0007]  [i0006]  [l0005]  [o0004]  [r0003]  [u0002]  [x0001]  [z0009]
```

Then:

```
$ ls \[[fn]*
[f0001]  [f0003]  [f0005]  [f0007]  [f0009]  [n0002]  [n0004]  [n0006]  [n0008]
[f0002]  [f0004]  [f0006]  [f0008]  [n0001]  [n0003]  [n0005]  [n0007]  [n0009]
$ ls \[*[48]*
[a0004]  [d0004]  [g0004]  [j0004]  [m0004]  [p0004]  [s0004]  [v0004]  [y0004]
[a0008]  [d0008]  [g0008]  [j0008]  [m0008]  [p0008]  [s0008]  [v0008]  [y0008]
[b0004]  [e0004]  [h0004]  [k0004]  [n0004]  [q0004]  [t0004]  [w0004]  [z0004]
[b0008]  [e0008]  [h0008]  [k0008]  [n0008]  [q0008]  [t0008]  [w0008]  [z0008]
[c0004]  [f0004]  [i0004]  [l0004]  [o0004]  [r0004]  [u0004]  [x0004]
[c0008]  [f0008]  [i0008]  [l0008]  [o0008]  [r0008]  [u0008]  [x0008]
```

The [ and ] are used for collections so if you want to search those you need to escape them with a \ in front of the [ and the ].

---

[b*] is a collection searching for a b:

```
~/tmp$ touch b111111
~/tmp$ touch bbbbb
~/tmp$ touch b
~/tmp$ ls [b*]
b
~/tmp$ ls b*
b  b111111  bbbbb
```

So a little bit different to a b with a wildcard. The would be "b*" without the [ and ] or if you want to include those "[b*]".

---

When this is the format:

```
name_of_rom[b1].nes
```

then

```
ls *\[b[0-9]\[*
```

- the 1st "*" will cover "name_of_rom". Basically any amount of characters before the ...
- `\[b[0-9]\[` will cover `[b0]` through `[b9]`.
- if there is more behind the 1st 0-9 use a "*" behind the "]". (so `\[b[0-9]*\[`.
- the last "*" will cover .nes. Basically any amount of characters.

---

I used "ls", if you get the results you want replace it by "rm".

Comment: See updated question, guy wants to delete matching filenames. I'm handing this over to you. :P